# Rails has_many :through validation nested records count by specific param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

I have models Workout and User which related as many to many through model
UserWorkout. And model UserWorkout has attribute :is_creator, which show what user was the creator. But Workout should have only one creator. What is the best way to add such validation?

```
 class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_workouts, inverse_of: :workout, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participants, through: :user_workouts, source: :user

  def creator
    participants.where(user_workouts: { is_creator: true }).order('user_workouts.created_at ASC').first
  end

end

class UserWorkout < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workout

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_workouts, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :workouts, through: :user_workouts

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is a design flaw in your DB structure. I think`is_creator` should not be in `UserWorkout` . It is a responsibility of `Workout`

In other words `Workout` can be created by a user and a `User` can create many `Workout` so it's a one-many relation between `User` and `Workout`

Keep a `created_by_id` in `Workout` and add a association in it. It will make lot of things easier and simpler.

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_workouts, inverse_of: :workout, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participants, through: :user_workouts, source: :user

  belongs_to :creator ,  class_name: "User", foreign_key: "created_by_id"

end
```

and there wont be any need to check the uniqueness as it's the single column in Workout

Now you don't need a complex query like every time you need to find the creator of a workout. It's a simple `belongs_to` association. Everything will be taken care by rails :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your DBMS, you could add a [filtered/partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html) on `workout_id where is_creator = true`

On the active record level, you can add a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

```
class UserWorkout
  validate :workout_has_only_one_creator

  private

  def workout_has_only_one_creator
    if self.class.find_by(workout_id: workout_id, is_creator: true)
      errors.add(:is_creator, 'can only have one creator')
    end
  end
```